# Magento grid column filter by text instead of id

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, filter, renderer

I created a column for my grid using renderer to change id to name like this:

```
$this->addColumn(
            'city_destination',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('test_shippingcost')->__('City Destination'),
                'index'  => 'city_destination',
                'type'=> 'text',
                'renderer'  => 'Test_ShippingCost_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_City'
            )
        );
```

But when i want try to filter the value using text, it won't budge unless i'm using id

renderer:

```
class Test_ShippingCost_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_City extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
  public function render(Varien_Object $row)
  {
    $id =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    $collection = Mage::getModel('test_shippingcost/city')->load($id);
    $value = $collection->getName();
    return $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all what is your renderer doing?
Then you may need to set a custom filter callback

Comment: this may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16591280/4349218

Comment: You say you are "using ID". Where? Is your column an options list or a text?

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis look at my updated question

Answer (score 1):

This may help

https://www.atwix.com/magento/grid-filter-for-columns/

Add a filter_condition_callback

```
$this->addColumn(
                'city_destination',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('test_shippingcost')->__('City Destination'),
                    'index'  => 'city_destination',
                    'type'=> 'text',
                    'renderer'  => 'Test_ShippingCost_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_City'
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_filterCityDestinationCallback')
                )
            );
```

Then add

```
   protected function _filterCityDestinationCallback($collection, $column) {
        $value= $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        if (!$value) {
              return $this;
        }
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where("main_table.name like ?","%$value%");                   
        return $this;
   }
```

Comment: the city name is not located in main_table,  so table city is connected to the main_table by using foreign key

Comment: You can use $value (name) to get the ids and filter the collection with them, but why don't you get the city destination name in your collection in the first place? You won't be needing a renderer or a custom filter.